# does anyone know how to integrate mqtt integration in react using react redux to dispatch the actions and store client payload as a mqttClient object?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, mqtt

Basically i wanted to integrate the mqtt in my react app. I want to connect to the mqtt when user login and disconnect when user logs out.

Firstly i created actions,reducers to dispatch the connection state and get client payload. It's connecting but the mqtt servers seems to be reconnecting in a loop with few secs. I want it to connect once and disconnect user logs out automatically. I globally initiated the mqtt client in the mqqtActions.js.

```
import { CONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE, CONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST, CONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS, DISCONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE, DISCONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST, DISCONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS } from "../constants/mqttConstants"

import mqtt from 'mqtt'
const mqttHost = "host ip address here";
const mqttPort = 8083;
const mqttUrl = `ws://${mqttHost}:${mqttPort}/mqtt`
const mqttOptions = {
    keepalive: 30,
    protocolId: 'MQTT',
    protocolVersion: 4,
    clean: true,
    reconnectPeriod: 1000,
    connectTimeout: 30 * 1000,
    clientId: "bharath",
    will: {
        topic: 'WillMsg',
        payload: 'Connection Closed abnormally..!',
        qos: 0,
        retain: false
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const mqttClient = mqtt.connect(mqttUrl, mqttOptions)
export const mqttConnect = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: CONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST
        })
        dispatch({
            type: CONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS,
            payload: mqttClient
        })
        //mqttClient.connect()
        localStorage.setItem('mqttClient', JSON.stringify(mqttClient))

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: CONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
        })

    }
}

export const mqttDisconnect = () => (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: DISCONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST })
         mqttClient.end()
        localStorage.removeItem('mqttClient')
        dispatch({
            type: DISCONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: DISCONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
        })
    }

}
```

I set up my reducer file like this:

```
import { CONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE, CONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST, CONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS, DISCONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE, DISCONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST, DISCONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS } from "../constants/mqttConstants"

export const connectMqttReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST:
            return { status: 'connecting' }
        case CONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS:
            return { status: 'connected', client: action.payload }
        case CONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE:
            return { status: 'connect', error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }

}
export const disconnectMqttReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DISCONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST:
            return { status: 'connected' }
        case DISCONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS:
            return { status: 'connect' }
        case DISCONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE:
            return { status: 'connected', error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }

}
```

Doing this i'm able to connect but its timestamp when connectedAt is changing continously.And also mqtt.connect() is not function error is also showing. I commented it out. I want to connect it once and disconnect when user login and logout actions are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1- Add the following to your environment file:

```
MQTT_HOST="host ip address here"
MQTT_PORT=8083
```

2- Add the following in your `Constants.js` file:

```
export const mqttUrl = `ws://${process.env.MQTT_HOST}:${process.env.MQTT_PORT}/mqtt`;

export const mqttOptions = {
  keepalive: 30,
  protocolId: 'MQTT',
  protocolVersion: 4,
  clean: true,
  reconnectPeriod: 1000,
  connectTimeout: 30 * 1000,
  clientId: 'bharath',
  will: {
    topic: 'WillMsg',
    payload: 'Connection Closed abnormally..!',
    qos: 0,
    retain: false,
  },
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

export const localStorageKeys = {
  mqttClient: 'mqttClient',
};
```

3- Create a new file which will hold all mqtt functionality `/src/clients/MqttClient.js`:

```
import mqtt from 'mqtt';
import { localStorageKeys, mqttOptions, mqttUrl } from '@/js/constants/Helpers';

let instance = null;

class MqttClient {
  constructor() {
    if (!instance) {
      instance = this;
    }

    return instance;
  }

  myMqtt;

  connect() {
    this.myMqtt = mqtt.connect(mqttUrl, mqttOptions);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.myMqtt.on('connect', () => {
        //add instance to local storage if it's not present (if you need it)
        const localStorageMqtt = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKeys.mqttClient);
        if (localStorageMqtt === null) {
          localStorage.setItem(localStorageKeys.mqttClient, JSON.stringify(this.myMqtt));
        }

        resolve();
      });
      this.myMqtt.on('error', (error) => reject(error));
    });
  }

  disconnect() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.myMqtt.end(false, {}, () => {
        this.myMqtt = null;

        //if you added it to the localstorage (on connect)
        localStorage.removeItem(localStorageKeys.mqttClient);

        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  subscribe(event) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.myMqtt) return reject('No mqtt connection.');

      return this.myMqtt.subscribe(event, (err) => {
        // Optional callback that you can use to detect if there's an error
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return reject(err);
        }

        return resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  publish(event, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.myMqtt) return reject('No mqtt connection.');

      return this.myMqtt.publish(event, data, {}, (err) => {
        // Optional callback that you can use to detect if there's an error
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return reject(err);
        }

        return resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  on(event, fun) {
    // No promise is needed here, but we're expecting one in the middleware.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.myMqtt) return reject('No mqtt connection.');

      this.myMqtt.on(event, fun);
      resolve();
    });
  }
}

export default MqttClient;
```

4- Create a new mqtt middleware in your store directory `/src/store/middleWares/MqttMiddleWare.js`:

```
export const mqttMiddleWare =
  (mqtt) =>
  ({ dispatch, getState }) =>
  (next) =>
  (action) => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState);
    }

    /*
     * Mqtt middleware usage.
     * promise: (mqtt) => mqtt.connect()
     * type: 'mqtt' //always (mqtt)
     * types: [REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE]
     */
    const { promise, type, types, ...rest } = action;

    if (type !== 'mqtt' || !promise) {
      // Move on! Not a mqtt request or a badly formed one.
      return next(action);
    }

    const [REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE] = types;
    next({ ...rest, type: REQUEST });

    return promise({ mqtt, dispatch, getState })
      .then((result) => {
        return next({ ...rest, result, type: SUCCESS });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE });
      });
  };
```

5- Update your store config to accept mqtt client as an argument then pass it to the mqtt middleware as follows `/src/store/configureStore.js`:

```
const middlewares = [];

// log redux data in development mode only
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  const { logger } = require('redux-logger');
  middlewares.push(logger);
}

const configureStore = (mqttClient) => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    /* preloadedState, */
    composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, mqttMiddleWare(mqttClient), ...middlewares)
    )
  );

  return store;
};
export default configureStore;
```

6- Instantiate your mqtt client in `/src/index.jsx` and pass it to your store:

```
const mqttClient = new MqttClient();
const store = configureStore(mqttClient);
```

7- Update your reducer as follows:

```
import { CONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE, CONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST, CONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS, DISCONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE, DISCONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST, DISCONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS } from "../constants/mqttConstants"

export const connectMqttReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST:
            return { connectionStatus: 'connecting' }
        case CONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS:
            return { connectionStatus: 'connected' }
        case CONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE:
            return { connectionStatus: 'connect failed', error: action.error }
        default:
            return state
    }

}
export const disconnectMqttReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DISCONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST:
            return { disconnectionStatus: 'disconnecting' }
        case DISCONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS:
            return { disconnectionStatus: 'disconnected' }
        case DISCONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE:
            return { disconnectionStatus: 'connect failed', error: action.error }
        default:
            return state
    }

}
```

8- Update your actions as follows:

- Connect action:

  ```
  export const startMqttConnection = () => ({
   type: 'mqtt',
   types: [CONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST, CONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS, CONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE],
   promise: ({ mqtt }) => mqtt.connect(),
  });
  ```
- Disconnect action:

  ```
  export const stopMqttConnection = () => ({
   type: 'mqtt',
   types: [DISCONNECT_MQTT_REQUEST, DISCONNECT_MQTT_SUCCESS, DISCONNECT_MQTT_FAILURE],
   promise: ({ mqtt }) => mqtt.disconnect(),
  });
  ```

9- dispatch the required action as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(startMqttConnection());

    return () => {
      if (connectionStatus === 'connected') {
        dispatch(stopMqttConnection());
      }
    };
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: In the useEffect you're again creating the mqtt connection doesn't it change client has it previously formed once we reload and make new connection?  doesn.t it effect the messages and topics we receive from the server

Comment: You can modify the `connect` method inside **MqttClient** to check if you have a client stored in the localstorage:
- use that client
- Else establish a new connection

Comment: Even in your solution you are establishing a new connection on every refresh